# Additional handling on Java Set Duplicate failure on Add

Tags: java

I'm accumulating unique objects in a `HashSet` from multiple calls to a service method outside my control which returns a `List<Record>`.

An additional requirement is if any duplicates are found in this process, I need to generate an email. I could check for duplicates myself and keep a `List<Record>` which inserts or skips, but then I wouldn't be using a `Set` which does this automatically, from an external List. Obviously there's no `try/catch` on Set Add failure, but is there a better way to do this?

```
HashSet<Record> set = new HashSet<Record>();
for (String org: orgs) {            
   // External service call
   List<Record> result = service.getRecords(org); 
   // Add All to Set (also need to detect duplicates with resulting logic)
   set.addAll(result);
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get what the problem is. What is the problem with `for(Record res:result) {if(set.contains(res)) duplicateFoundCode(res); set.add(res);}` ?

Comment: Thanks, but is that just like using a List? I could use a List have the same code.

Comment: BTW, one problem with your tip is that I get a List<Object> back, I would need an extra traversal every time I get that preliminary result back to detect dupes.

Comment: Well, checking element existence for sets take constant time. So it only takes one traversal over the returned list to find duplicates. And for the objects, I guess you can cast them and go from there.

Comment: If the requirement is just to generate email when a duplicate is found, why don't you just compare set size before and after addAll method? If the result equals PreviousSetSize + ListSize then no duplicate, if it is smaller then there is duplicate. You don't need to iterate.

Comment: I could do that, but it's ugly to keep track of the initial count just for comparion purposes. Joop Eggen suggested an elegant `!set.add()` result which adds and checks the result on a single element.

Comment: How come 4 lines of code(If you use java 8 it is also 1 line though the answer is not using it) is better than 1 line of code, plus using if for every iteration. It gives you exact record though, so use it at your own purposes. If you need just the count of duplicates in the email use my solution, you will have to use a counter to increase if you need count otherwise while trying to escape holding previous set size.

Comment: That's true. Your answer avoids the iteration. I just need to declare variables, but I'll consider it, it's also good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit, whether result can contain duplicate records itself,
whether one can handle a third occurrence of a record irrespectively.

```
Set<Record> set = new HashSet<>();
for (String org: orgs) {            
    // External service call
    List<Record> result = service.getRecords(org); 
    // Add All to Set (also need to detect duplicates with resulting logic)
    for (Record record: result) {
        if (!set.add(record)) {
            // Handle duplicate by individual record:
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
Set<Record> set = new HashSet<>();
Set<Record> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
for (String org: orgs) {            
    // External service call
    List<Record> result = service.getRecords(org); 
    // Add All to Set (also need to detect duplicates with resulting logic)
    Set<Record> duplicateResult = new .HashSet<>(result);
    duplicateResult.retainAll(set);
    duplicates.addAll(duplicateResult);
    set.addAll(result);
}
for (Record record: duplicates) {
    // Handle duplicate once:
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes that's a good solution. At least `!set.add(record)` saves me the trouble of doing `contains` which I would have had to do otherwise. Unfortunately still have to traverse the temporary call result but overall it's much better.